# How does Rails distinguish instant variables that belong to different users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am following a RailsCast on implementing Facebook API. In the `User` model, I have a method:

```
  def facebook
     @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
```

which creates an instant variable that can be shared with other methods within User model.

My question is:

If my Rails app has 100 users online, each of them create one instance `@facebook`, how does Rails know which `@facebook` is associated with with user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance variables are associated with the instance of the object they belong to.

Users interact with their own `User` instance because it's associated with their session or a specific request. Requests are processed using request-specific instances of controllers that in turn deal with a specific instance of a `User`, hence `@facebook` value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder if I have session, will user instance tied to a specific session be recreated every time a request is sent?

Comment: @AdamNYC Seems like this should be pretty easy to answer, no? That said, it depends on several factors, like where your sessions live, how you're handling auth/auth, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I actually don't know. But may be it's time for me to go back to the basics.

Comment: @AdamNYC Well, you know where the user class is-maybe adding some log statement could help.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. There is no such thing as "online" in a web app, every time you click a link, a request a sent. For that request, all classes are instantiated, including running the code you posted.

After the request is completed, those classes are disposed of.

Comment: Ah, I see. Now I know a bit more about "stateless". What happens if I use @facebook to query on the background?

Comment: What do you mean by "on the background"? delayed_job? any other queue? Or just a method call?

Comment: delayed_job serializes the tasks to database, so it will be the same data in the task. Usually, such tasks involves passing the user object into it as well, so when the task is executed, that user object will be taken.